# Android Recyclerview ItemTouchHelper - long press goes "through" children views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Not sure if the title is totally clear. What I am trying to do is attach an ItemTouchHelper to a parent recyclerview to allow its items to be dragged in the vertical direction. Each item of the recyclerview has its own list of horizontal elements that can also be dragged horizontally, but that doesn't seem to be relevant here since as I will show this occurs on all children of the parent recyclerview (the button in the gif).

I want to highlight the items when long clicked and dragging for visual clarity.

The problem is anywhere I long press on the item of the vertical recyclerview item, it calls the `onSelectedChanged` for that item and thus highlights the item (since that is where I turn on highlighting). Even if I am long pressing something on top of it. See the gif for clarity. Basically long clicking "through" the views.

[image]

The interesting thing to note is that when long clicking the button, the child recyclerview that allows for reordering horizontally does not have this issue. That is, its `onSelectedChanged` is not called and there is no momentarily flicker of that view being highlighted. I assume that is due to the order of the children in the parent's relative layout (seen below). I bring this up only because at first I thought this entire issue had to do with having overlapping recyclerviews that have ItemTouchHelpers attached to them, but it appears that was a red herring.

What I want is for the item touch helper of the vertical recyclerview to be ignored if something on top of it is long clicked.

I have been trying all sorts of things and nothing has worked. Hacky as it is, I've thought of having a flag that is set to true whenever a child is long pressed and then I would check for that to determine if I show the parent as highlighted. But even that won't work since the parent's onSelectedChange happens first anyway.

I've also tried to play with `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)` but that has not worked. I tried placing it on the child views of the parent item. From the docs I don't think that is applicable here anyway since this is issue is only for long clicks/dragging, not singular clicks.

Single clicks have no issue and are not passing through to the parent. In other words, if I click the button (not long click) then only the button receives the onClick event, not the parent behind it.

I'm hoping I'm just missing something in the XML or the way I am using the Dispatcher, since otherwise I really can't see a clean way of fixing this other than just forgoing the highlight on the parent all together. Would greatly appreciate any help.

Code:

ItemTouchHelper for vertical recyclerview:

```
private final ItemTouchHelper verticalDragDispatcher = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, 0) {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder dragged, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        int fromPosition = dragged.getAdapterPosition();
        int toPosition = target.getAdapterPosition();
        mList.swap(fromPosition, toPosition);
        recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSelectedChanged(@Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
        super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState);
        // called even if another view on top of this viewholder was long pressed
        if (viewHolder instanceof DraggableViewHolder && actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_DRAG) {
            DraggableViewHolder itemViewHolder = (DraggableViewHolder) viewHolder;
            itemViewHolder.highlight();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clearView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);
        if (viewHolder instanceof DraggableViewHolder) {
            DraggableViewHolder itemViewHolder = (DraggableViewHolder) viewHolder;
            itemViewHolder.clearHighlight();
        }
    }
});
```

XML of the item for the vertical recycler view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/inner_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"/>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

XML of root layout that contains the vertical recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/vertical_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="4dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not totally solve this but found an acceptable workaround. In the ItemTouchHelper.Callback, I instead highlight the item in the `onChildDraw` method and only when `isCurrentlyActive == true` instead of in `onSelectedChanged`. This prevents the highlight of the parent item from occurring only when the inner recyclerview is being re-arranged which is close enough for me.

```
    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        if (isCurrentlyActive && viewHolder instanceof DraggableViewHolder && actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_DRAG) {
            DraggableViewHolder itemViewHolder = (DraggableViewHolder) viewHolder;
            itemViewHolder.highlight();
        }
    }
```